# git rebase on top of HEAD with unrelated history, deleting everything before

Tags: git, rebase

Given the following commit graph:

```
A--B--C (origin/foo)

D--E (foo)
```

I want to achieve this:

```
A--B--C--F (foo origin/foo)
```

`F` being a rebase commit that essentially contains the changes from my local history `D--E` and undoes/empties everything else before it. Ultimately replacing the entire remote HEAD state with my local state (`foo@{E}`), just changing the history to be rebased on top of the remote commits. My environment does not allow for a simple `git push --force`, I have to keep the remote commits.

I tried `git rebase -X theirs origin/foo` (with the inverted strategy option), but it kept all non-conflicting changes from the remote, which I want deleted in the same diff. `git rebase -s theirs origin/foo` did not work as expected (`git: 'merge-theirs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`).

I could `git revert` every single other commit after doing the rebase, and then squash them into one before committing, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the change-apply part, you could try `git cherry-pick E` if `D-E` are *two* commits. If they represent a lot of commits, first create the patch between them,

```
git diff --binary D E > patch.diff
```

and then apply the patch,

```
git apply -3 patch.diff
```

There could be conflicts in both ways.

> Ultimately replacing the entire remote HEAD state with my local state (foo@{E})

Do you mean that you want F's files to be exactly the same with E's? If so, applying the changes between D and E does not work. Instead, you need to create a commit, whose tree is the same with E's tree and whose parent is C.

```
# Replace C and E with their sha1 values
git commit-tree -p C -m "some message" E^{tree}
```

It creates a commit and prints its sha1 value. Then update `foo` to point at the new commit.

```
git update-ref refs/heads/foo $newcommit
```

If `foo` is currently checked out, you could also run `git reset $newcommit --hard`.

Comment: For the second option (commit the exact same content as E on top of C): `git reset --soft C && git commit` from `foo` branch would also work

Comment: @LeGEC Thanks for pointing it out. In daily usage I'm a bit scared of `git reset --soft` between 2 diverged branches as if it's not under my control.

Comment: oh, but actually, `git reset --soft` should be the least scary of the `git reset` commands :) it is the one which preserves both your index and worktree, so you can actually safely return to the state you were in before (staging area included)